# How to insert a dataframe into a snowflake database

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert a R dataframe to snowflake database table using `dbWritetable()`. It is only inserting couple of rows, not the entire dataframe.

> error : Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 00000: [Snowflake][Support] (40465) String data truncated while performing conversion.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information as there is not a lot to go on here.  The Create Table statement, sample of the first few rows of data being loaded? R sessionInfo() for your R session so we know what R package versions your running, also what version of the Snowflake ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Are the Char/Varchar fields in the target table defined large enough to accommodate the input data for character/factor fields in your dataframe?  You can use something like this to get the max length per column.

```
df <- data.frame(a = (c('fred','flintstone')),
                 b = as.factor(c('barney','rubble')),
                 c = (c(1,2)))
library(stringr)
lapply(df, function(x) max(str_length(x)))
```